# Adding titles to each facet in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I am curious if it is possible to put axis titles on each facet in a facet_wrap. I can get close but I can't get x and y to display properly. The code is currently displaying both x and y on the same axis. I know this isn't exactly how it is supposed to function, but I want to see if it can be done without going to something more complex (arranging separate plots with grob or something).

In short, I would like y_names and x_names to appear on their respective axes.

```
testdat<-data.frame(x_names=c("A","B","C"),x_vals=c(1,2,3),y_names=c("B","C","A"), y_vals=c(2,3,1))
ggplot(testdat, aes(x_vals, y_vals)) +
  geom_point(pch=21) +
  facet_wrap(y_names~x_names, 
             ncol=1,
             scales="free",
             strip.position="left",
             labeller=as_labeller(c(A= "Apple",
                                    B= "Bread",
                                    C= "Cantaloupe"))
  )+
  theme( strip.background = element_blank(),
         strip.placement = "outside",
         axis.title.x=element_blank(),
         axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean - perhaps this?

```r
library(ggplot2)

testdat <- data.frame(x_names = c("A","B","C"),
                      x_vals  = c(1, 2, 3),
                      y_names = c("B", "C", "A"), 
                      y_vals  = c(2, 3, 1))

ggplot(testdat, aes(x_vals, y_vals)) +
  geom_point(pch = 21) +
  facet_grid(y_names ~ x_names, 
             labeller = as_labeller(c(A = "Apple",
                                      B = "Bread",
                                      C = "Cantaloupe")),
              switch = "both") +
  theme( strip.background = element_blank(),
         strip.placement  = "outside",
         axis.title.x     = element_blank(),
         axis.title.y     = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The OP seems to want to have three (possibly completely unrelated) plots for when the two faceting factors are completely correlated. This is equivalent to faceting on a single variable. However, we want a separate axis for each facet. There are probably several ways to achieve this directly in ggplot, but they are all quite convoluted and include adding custom annotations.

I think in this case by far the easiest and most freedom-preserving way is to add plots together using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`, which doesn't require any hacking or grob manipulation. It's as easy as:

```r
p1 <- ggplot(filter(testdat, x_names == "A", y_names == "B"), aes(x_vals, y_vals)) + 
        geom_point() + labs(x = "Apple", y = "Banana")

p2 <- ggplot(filter(testdat, x_names == "B", y_names == "C"), aes(x_vals, y_vals)) +
        geom_point() + labs(x = "Banana", y = "Cherry")

p3 <- ggplot(filter(testdat, x_names == "C", y_names == "A"), aes(x_vals, y_vals)) +
        geom_point() + labs(x = "Cherry", y = "Apple")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1 , p2, p3)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: No, it would be one column and each facet in the column will have an x and y axis title instead of a single title at the bottom. By manipulating the strip location, I can do it so each has an X or each has a Y, but I can figure out how to do it so each has an x and each has a y.

Comment: I see. Doing it that way you could effectively have three plots which may have nothing to do with each other: it could be date vs price, rainfall versus banana yield and height versus shoe size. Except you want to do that by faceting?

Comment: If you won't be offended I will leave this open a little while longer to see if there are any other solutions out there. I am kind of hoping for something that doesn't require the creation of separate plots.

Comment: @TBP it is possible to do it with facets and without separate calls to ggplot, using text annotations as axis labels, but this would take more code to do and is definitely a hack (in that this is not what facets are designed for). Whether you like it or not, you _are_ producing 3 different plots. It's just that you are trying to do it by using a tool that wasn't designed for it. It's like "can I use a screwdriver to hammer a nail in? I really don't want to have to use a hammer" The answer is "yes', but it will be harder to do and the results won't be as good.

Answer (score 1):

Question:

**"I am curious if it is possible to put axis titles on each facet in a facet_wrap."**

Answer:

**Yes it is possible.**

However... Should you do it? No.

Faceting adds an additional dimension to your plots, i.e., given an **x** and a **y** variable, a third variable is used to subset the data, say, **z**.

You have an implied request for code to display plots with **multiple x and y** variables, as such you should not use faceting. Instead, there should be three distinct plots: Allan Cameron has kindly produced a good solution.

The ggplot2 book explains what faceting should be used for here: https://ggplot2-book.org/facet.html.